# AngularJS date filter with condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I use ng-bind and the date filter to output a time of a date.

```
<span ng-bind="ctrl.model.myDate | date:'HH:mm'"><span>
```

Now I would like to be able to switch the output between 12 and 24h format, with this filter: date:'HH:mm' and date:'hh:mm'

Therefore I have a property:

```
model.is24h= true
```

How can I insert a condition into the ng-bind expression to evaluate my property to output in 12h or 24h format?

Something like:

```
<span ng-bind="ctrl.model.myDate | {{ctrl.model.is24h: date:'HH:mm' || date:'hh:mm'}}"><span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a new filter with the variable as an argument

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13224/

HTML

```
<span ng-bind="myDate | newDate:is24h"></span>
<button type="button" ng-click="is24h = !is24h">Swap</button>
```

JS

```
myApp.filter('newDate', function ($filter) {
    return function (input, arg) {
        var hFormat = arg ? 'HH' : 'hh';
        return $filter('date')(new Date(input), hFormat  + '.mm');
    };
});
```

Comment: why do you add toUpperCase() inside the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your filter code for this condition.

```
angular.module('yourmodule').filter('date', function ($filter, $scope) {
            return function (input) {
                if (input == null) { return ""; }
                if ($scope.is24h) {
                    return $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'HH:mm').toUpperCase();
                }

                return $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'hh:mm').toUpperCase();
            };
        });
```

html should be

```
<span ng-bind="ctrl.model.myDate | date"><span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use trenary operator in directive parameter:

```
<span ng-bind="ctr.model.myDate | date:(ctrl.model.is24h?'HH':'hh')+':mm'"><span>
```

Comment: 2 watchers for this use case seems not to be the right way for me